# Is the uncountable intersection of linear subspaces also a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For finite intersection, we know it's a linear subspace.

Is the countably infinite (non-empty) intersection of linear subspaces also a linear subspace? What about a non-countable intersection?

Answer (score 9):

**Any** intersection of linear subspaces of a vector space is also a linear subspace. The cardinality of the set of subspaces doesn't matter. And the proof remains the same when we change the number of subspaces.

Answer (score 2):

This will be true no matter which intersection is taken.

The idea is as follows, take $V=\cap W_\alpha$ for some set of subspaces indexed by $\alpha$. Then for every $v,w\in V$ we have $v,w\in W_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ so that $v+w\in W_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ so that $v+w\in V$. Similarly for scaler multiplication $v\in V\Rightarrow \forall \alpha: v\in W_\alpha\Rightarrow \forall\alpha: cv\in W_\alpha\Rightarrow cv\in V$.